# Which WCF security mode to use

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I've recently built a WCF service and am now ready to add security to it. I'd like to have it available over https, internet facing and the client will authenticate with a username and password. I'm only going to have 3 users so I want to make the authentication as simple as possible. Also, requests will be one at a time, where I would like the requester to authenticate each time (which, to me, means message client credentialing). Also, this will be hosted in IIS6. My reading on WCF shows a lot of [security option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836.aspx)s and frankly I'm overwhelmed on what to choose.

Given the requirements above, which configuration option should I choose and how should I configure WCF. Are there any sample projects that implement security like what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Service Configuration :**

```
Binding : wsHttpBinding
Security Mode : Message
ClientCredentialMode : UserName
```

**Client Configuration :**

```
CertificateValidationMode : PeerOrChainTrust
```

**Proxy :**

```
proxy.clientCredentials.UserName.Username
proxy.clientCredentials.UserName.Password
```

Also you can see the following URL :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa967563(v=vs.90).aspx